# How does the new Unity 2017 naming convention work?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity has moved from the release tags like 5.6.3 etc... to 2017.2

What does each section of the new naming convention mean, where it's not obviously a year/release num.

For Example

- 2017.2.b
- 2017.2.0f2-MRTP
- 2017.2.1f1
- 2017.1.2p4

Comment: My Guess would be:  [year].[major].[minor][?]  

The ? might be Beta and Patch for b & p?

with MRTP being the Mixed Reality Technical Preview

Comment: A similar question was asked on the [Unity Forum](https://answers.unity.com/questions/555890/what-does-the-f-stand-for-in-the-version-number.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a largely used convention.

Softwares like PyCharm and now Unity 3D use it for versioning following the scheme: [year].[major].[minor]. Some software and even OS (Ubuntu, for example) use a different kind of conventional, much similar to the new Unity convention: [year].[month] so you get Ubuntu 11.10 which means it was launched in October 2011.

I believe that is called Calendar Versioning. (I might be wrong). If you'd like, you can read more about it here: Calendar Versioning - https://calver.org/#scheme.

Like MaddoxSt previous said:

```
a stands for alpha
b stands for beta
rc stands for release candidate
f stands for final
p stands for patch
```

Answer (score 3):

There are specifics to what they mean. 
For example

- a = alpha
- b = beta
- f = final release
- p = patch

So they are being named that way :)